# Tcl Programming sorting text files with name

Tags: tcl

I am a new one in TCL programming.
my question in I have multiple text files 
(Eg: `sysDataUpdate_1119041809_1.sql`,`sysDataUpdate_1119041809_2.sql` ....... `sysDataUpdate_1119041809_50.sql`) in a directory "`ABC`".

Now I want .sql file with highest number like "`sysDataUpdate_1119041809_50.sql`" ?

Answer (score 1):

```
set filesList [lsort -decreasing [glob -nocomplain "ABC/*.sql"]]
if {[llength $filesList]>0} {
    set reqFile [lindex $filesList 0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `glob` to list the files, and `lsort -dictionary` to put them in the type of order you describe. Finally, using `end` with `lindex` will give the largest value:

```
set files [glob -directory ABC sysDataUpdate*.sql]
set sorted [lsort -dictionary $files]
set largest [lindex $sorted end]
```

You can compose this into one line if you want:

```
set largest [lindex [lsort -dictionary [glob -directory ABC sysDataUpdate*.sql]] end]
```